# Chinese visa limited to 30 days (new immigration law)?

Tags: visas, china, hong-kong

I have heard that from 1st September China will have a new immigration law and it will not be possible any longer to get a Chinese Tourist Visa in Hong Kong for longer than 1 month.

Does anyone have precise info?

Comment: The tourist 'L' visa is typically for 30 days each time anyway. Longer term L visa are possible under some circumstances.

Comment: In June I entered China through HK and I got a visa for  3 month without any issue: applied in the morning the visa was ready in the afternoon.
I hope it will be easy to get another Visa now for 3 month.
I'm just scarred about this new regularization

Comment: It might be worth elaborating the original question. A single entry L visa will last for 3 months, however it will only allow a stay of 30 days inside mainland China.

Answer (score 7):

There is no such regulation.

Visa consultancies in Hong Kong [do not list](http://www.visainchina.com/) such a change in the list of changes that will take effect on 1st of September. There are changes regarding [extensions in Shanghai](http://www.visainchina.com/lvisa.htm) that will be bound to a proof that you have enough money for each day you want to extend the visa, but this does not touch the initial visa duration.

There might be a misunderstanding for emergency visas [that can now be issued](http://lawandborder.com/faq-new-visa-law-and-regulations/#1_What8217s_the_difference) by public security bureaus on the border. Those can be only 30 days. Normal visa issued by the standard authorities such as foreign consulates can be still 180 days.

Comment: although the question is really old - the real answer ( for any given time period ) would depend on the OP nationality which is not stated in the question . Local embassies can potentially have such regulations ( again - for any given time - period )